# Subquery returning nulls but unable to use it

Tags: mysql

I'm using a query that will select certain data, and my challenge right now is a sub-query is returning a `NULL` value, however I need to ***USE*** that `NULL` value.

Here is this part of the query that I'm using and a table for some references: (The rest is useless to this issue)

```
    CREATE TABLE urgarm (
        `urgarmID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `rfid` VARCHAR(24) NULL,
        `dateissued` date DEFAULT NULL,
        `lastdatein` date DEFAULT NULL,
        `statuscode` VARCHAR(1) NULL
    );
```

Now the Query:

```
    SELECT
        MAX(c.urgarmID)
    FROM
        urgarm c
    WHERE
        c.rfid = '3035307B2831B380E05E398B'  AND
        //This is the subquery that is returning null and I NEED this null value.
        c.lastdatein = (
            SELECT
                MAX(d.lastdatein)
            FROM
                urgarm d
            WHERE
                d.rfid = c.rfid  AND
                d.dateissued IN (
                    SELECT
                        MAX(e.dateissued)
                    FROM
                        urgarm e
                    WHERE
                        e.rfid = d.rfid
                )
        )
```

My question is how can I use this null value? I understand the only way to really use a `NULL` is by using `IS NULL`. But how can I do that for this case?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `c.lastdatein <=> (...)`

Comment: @juergend Please submit this as the answer, because you are correct. I've never seen that operator in my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [*null-save equal* operator `<=>` in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

```
c.lastdatein <=> (...)
```